# Python formatting text to a Dict

Tags: python

I have a text document need to format it to a dictionary. I'm new to python so totally confused how to achieve it please can one help out on this

```
Hi this is a employee document 
200 Name 200 Order # 200 code # 200 Case #
george,bendti  11-11111 1111111111 11111111
below are the details report 
200 Birth Date 200 Age 200 Gender 200 Area   200 Account #
10/14/1944 75 Y Female  Newyork 111111
```

```
{
       "Name":"george,bendti",
       "Order #":"11-11111",
       "code #":"1111111111",
       "Case #":"11111111",
       "Birth Date":"10/14/1944",
       "Age":"75 Y",
       "Gender":"Female",
       "Area":"Newyork",
       "Account":"111111", 
}
```

Comment: Is there any special separator present in the text file which can indicate the end of a record? Otherwise simply read the file and then split the line on space (might be wrong) and then assign key:value accordingly?

Comment: @adithya there is no special separator present, literally confused how to achieve this.

Comment: Your text does not have any significant patterns to be iteratively turned into a dictionary - but if you were to use regular expressions (`re` module in Python) and had patterns that were consistent you could create dictionaries from slightly different inputs.

Comment: @leopardxpreload  I have updated the input text is there any chance now

Comment: @Aditya I have updated the input text is there any chance now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use `re.split()`:

```
d = '''Hi this is a employee document 
200 Name 200 Order # 200 code # 200 Case #
george,bendti  11-11111 1111111111 11111111
below are the details report 
200 Birth Date 200 Age 200 Gender 200 Area   200 Account #
10/14/1944 75 Y Female  Newyork 111111
'''
import re

dct = d.split('\n') # Splitting the lines
dct = [re.split(' 200 | 200|200 ',d) for i,d in enumerate(dct) if i%3] # Splitting the column names
dct = [re.split(' (?!Y)',d[0]) if i%2 else d for i,d in enumerate(dct)] # Splitting the column values
dct = [[a for a in d if a] for d in dct] # Removing empty strings 
d = {k:v  for i in range(0,len(dct),2) for k,v in zip(dct[i],dct[i+1])} # Creating dictionary

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'george,bendti', 'Order #': '11-11111', 'code #': '1111111111', 'Case #': '11111111', 'Birth Date': '10/14/1944', 'Age': '75 Y', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Area  ': 'Newyork', 'Account #': '111111'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is that you have multiple inputs that follow a similar structure with consistent patterns - you could use `re` - Its hard to parse text that isn't in a very obvious structure into a dictionary - but regular expression can be quite powerful.

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint

input_string = r'Hi this is a employee document \
200 Name 200 Order # 200 code # 200 Case # \
george,bendti  11-11111 1111111111 11111111 \
below are the details report \
200 Birth Date 200 Age 200 Gender 200 Area   200 Account # \
10/14/1944 75 Y Female  Newyork 111111'


my_dict = {}
my_dict['Name'] = re.search(r'[a-z]+,[a-z]+', input_string.lower()).group()
my_dict['Order'] = re.search(r'[0-9]{2,}-[0-9]{5,}', input_string).group()
my_dict['Case'] = re.search(r'[0-9]{8,}', input_string).group()
my_dict['Birth Date'] = re.search(r'[0-9]{2,}/[0-9]{2,}/[0-9]{2,}', input_string).group()
my_dict['Age'] = re.search(r'[0-9]+ Y', input_string).group()
my_dict['Gender'] = re.search(r'(female|male)', input_string.lower()).group()

pprint(my_dict)
```

I recommend [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) - this site has a clear and interactive manner of testing regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @leopardxpreload. but the position of the text will keep changing, positioning the records will not work for future text data

Comment: Position doesn't matter, its the pattern that matters